# Creating a Procedure in Oracle to create View

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a procedure in oracle, which upon calling from PL SQL block will create a view in database from which i will query data for a report. I am new to Oracle and need help with this code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_VIEW 
(
  TO_DT IN Date 
) AS 
BEGIN
  Create or Replace view BORR_DUR As
  SELECT e."Deal_No", (Select "DeskName" From MM_S_DESK Where e."DeskCode" = MM_S_DESK."DeskCode") Facility, e."Remarks" Counterparty, 
m."MaturityDate", m."PriRedem" Principal, 

(select MAX("INTEREST_RATE") from MM_BOR_PLA_PAR d 
WHERE e."Deal_No" = d."DEAL_NO" and "INTERESTINPUTDATE" <= to_dt)/100 yield, (m."MaturityDate" - To_date(to_dt,'dd/mm/yyyy')) Days_to_Mat,
Round(((m."MaturityDate" - To_date(to_dt,'dd/mm/yyyy'))/365)/ (1+((select MAX("INTEREST_RATE") from MM_BOR_PLA_PAR d 
WHERE e."Deal_No" = d."DEAL_NO" and "INTERESTINPUTDATE" <= to_dt)/100)),4) MDURATION


FROM MM_T_BORROWING e, MM_T_BORROWING_PM_DETAIL m
Where e."DeskCode" in ('10','11','12','13') and e."Value_Date" <= to_dt and e."Maturity_Date" > to_dt and e."Status" not in ('C', 'D', 'Z', '0','X') 
and e."Deal_No" = m."Deal_No" and "PriRedem" > '0' and m."MaturityDate" > to_dt;

END CREATE_VIEW;
```

On Compilation, i get PLS00103 error which says

> encountered the symbol "Create" when expecting one of the
>   following....

Any help in solving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to do something like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE or REPLACE .....'` whole of the statement goes inside execute immediate.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What would you gain by writing a procedure rather than just running the CREATE VIEW statement?

Comment: i would rather run a statement as well but finding it difficult to run directly in PL SQL, Execute Immediate is not available in 6i, and simple execute or execute query aint working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want execute SQL statement which is dynamic you have to use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** statement

First , you don't need double quotes in fields name , after that you can try the query of the view and check if it runs without errors .

Put the create replace view... statement in an variable and in your procedure call :

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE view_string_variable ;
END;
/
```

Comment: The query to create view works perfect and do what is required. when i put statement in variable as 'view_string_variable ('Create or Replace view Borr_Dur As.....'  , I get this error, 

Error(11,22): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     constant exception <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref    char time timestamp interval date binary national character    nchar

Comment: One of your sintax error(pharentesis needed) is around here "INTERESTINPUTDATE" <= to_dt)/100 yield , i want suggest you to delete double quotes where you don't need , with strings you should put everything between single quotes , but when you have single quotes inside your script , to escape from sintax error you have to put this between double quotes . ex  (''10'',''11'',''12'',''13'')

Comment: This is exactly what my problem is, i tried with a simple query it worked, everything else is fine except that i have values passed as string within the query while the query itself is going as string. so values such as ('10','11') etc cannot be compiled. I have tried replacing single quote with double, but it doesnt help.

Comment: But why you need quotes for numbers? are they declared as varchar ? if not delete quotes from there

Comment: issue resolved, i actually had to use '' i.e. single quote pressed twice and i was using " double quotes which were creating problem. Thanks for your help frank. really appreciate it.